# Will --bind-address in Wget over-ride the IP address of the interface from which packets are routed

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, wget

I am trying to simulate network client (preferably C code) that runs on a machine (laptop/PC). On start, it negotiate a new IP address through DHCP from the router of the network the machine is part of. Post obtaining IP address, it is suppose to make http requests (downloads/uploads) as per a configuration file.

The setup is primarily to spawn multiple of such clients for the purpose of stress testing the router.

I came across https://github.com/saravana815/dhtest which does the part of DHCP negotiation. It creates a random mac address & gets an IP from the router for the same.

The next step is to extend the client to have http calls. I started looking into https://github.com/jay/wget & the flag `--bind-address` caught my attention

```
 --bind-address=ADDRESS    bind to ADDRESS (hostname or IP) on local host.\n"),
```

What I understand is - purpose of this flag is to select appropriate interface on the machine . On looking closer to the source, I found the snippet below which gets kicked in for the flag

```
static bool
resolve_bind_address (struct sockaddr *sa)
{
  struct address_list *al;

  /* Make sure this is called only once.  opt.bind_address doesn't
     change during a Wget run.  */
  static bool called, should_bind;
  static ip_address ip;
  if (called)
    {
      if (should_bind)
        sockaddr_set_data (sa, &ip, 0);
      return should_bind;
    }
  called = true;

  al = lookup_host (opt.bind_address, LH_BIND | LH_SILENT);
  if (!al)
    {
      /* #### We should be able to print the error message here. */
      logprintf (LOG_NOTQUIET,
                 _("%s: unable to resolve bind address %s; disabling bind.\n"),
                 exec_name, quote (opt.bind_address));
      should_bind = false;
      return false;
    }

  /* Pick the first address in the list and use it as bind address.
     Perhaps we should try multiple addresses in succession, but I
     don't think that's necessary in practice.  */
  ip = *address_list_address_at (al, 0);
  address_list_release (al);

  sockaddr_set_data (sa, &ip, 0);
  should_bind = true;
  return true;
}
```

The function `sockaddr_set_data (sa, &ip, 0);` looks as below

```
static void
sockaddr_set_data (struct sockaddr *sa, const ip_address *ip, int port)
{
  switch (ip->family)
    {
    case AF_INET:
      {
        struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa;
        xzero (*sin);
        sin->sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin->sin_port = htons (port);
        sin->sin_addr = ip->data.d4;
        break;
      }
#ifdef ENABLE_IPV6
    case AF_INET6:
      {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa;
        xzero (*sin6);
        sin6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        sin6->sin6_port = htons (port);
        sin6->sin6_addr = ip->data.d6;
#ifdef HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SCOPE_ID
        sin6->sin6_scope_id = ip->ipv6_scope;
#endif
        break;
      }
#endif /* ENABLE_IPV6 */
    default:
      abort ();
    }
}
```

I am not exactly a network/socket expert. What I want to confirm is - does explicitly adding an IP address to the packets that Wget is sending will over-ride the IP address that OS would set for these packets when they leave a particular interface ?

The answer to this question would help me decide if I should create a separate logical interface for every network client I look to simulate or if I can completely do away with it (I prefer the latter).

Answer (score 0):

The packets will be routed via that interface to which the socket is bound. The IP  address can be virtual or the primary IP of the Ethernet interface. And the IP determines which physical interface which shall be used for communication.

You can create multiple virtual IP addresses on a given physical interface and spawn clients each binding to different IP. This presents a case of varied sources for your router (simulation) Though all will be using the same physical interface.

Comment: Since dhclient is getting a random IP through DHCP for a random mac address, how exactly mapping to interface will work in this case ? Can you be more specific to this particular case. Wget only allows to specify bind address. Does it try to figure out interface based on IP address because if it does, in current scenario, this will lead to an error .

Comment: If I understood you correctly, are you asking how would wget know the IP address since the IP address is got by DHCP?

Comment: No. Consider dhclient & wget as 2 independent binary I am using in my shell script. I first launch dhtest to negotiate dhcp & I modify dhtest to dump IP address so that I have it in my script. Now I launch wget with bind-address as that ip address.

Comment: OK. So the bind will happen on that IP address that you got with dhclient. That physical interface will be chosen which is now bound to that IP

Comment: I guess I am not clear in my q. Dhtest runs like ./dhtest -m <random mac address> & it gets IP for this random mac address. Router in its arp cache has this IP address & random mac.